# Wget best practices on large files

Tags: wget

I have a text file (150GB) in size, with around 2.5 billion links I need to download.

I am wondering if I wget this file, if wget puts the entire files contents in memory, and if it will potentially crash the machine.

I am also interested to know on some best practices when downloading this amount of links, for example, will the directory it downloads to become unusable with this amount of files?

What about resuming, Does wget check from the top where the download stopped or failed, cause that could take a long time.

Does it keep a log? Will the log file be really big? Is the log file stored in memory before its saved somewhere? Can I disable the log.

Basically, I am interested in the best practice in downloading a file of this size. Each link I am downloading is around 250 bytes.

Many thanks

Comment: You are limited by the virtual memory memory size and file size that `wget` and the filesystem support. You are also limited to the maximum directory entries that the filesystem supports.